# IndentationError but it's not mixing up tabs and spaces

Tags: python

When I try and run my script it insists that there's an IndentationError on line 10, the def **init**(self): line. Looking it up I tried some of the common fixes I've seen, checking to make sure tabs and spaces aren't mixed up, making sure loops are properly structured, but nothing's working!

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
  """Overall game assets and behavior"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        
        self.settings = Settings()pi
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        # Set the background
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

                # Redraw the screen during each pass through the pass
                self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
                self.ship.blitme()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

If anyone can tell me what's happening that'd be appreciated. Trying out Python so late into my coding life is a doozy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
class AlienInvasion:
  """Overall game assets and behavior"""
```

Should be this:

```
class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall game assets and behavior"""
```

So that it matches the next definition:

```
    def __init__(self):
```

Comment: Oh wow. I'm really not used to code being that sensitive to spacing, I had no idea the doc lines had to line up as well, I assumed since they were akin to comments it would be ignored when compiled. Shows what I know! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Endured_Programmer You're welcome! Note that the doc lines are actually code (string literals), not comments! That is the reason they need to be aligned properly.

Comment: They *aren't* akin to comments - they are *strings* that simply have some additional special treatment. Aside from creating documentation, it's essentially the same as how you could have `"hello world"` on a line by itself in the middle of the code, and it wouldn't *do* anything - it would just mean to figure out what that string is, and then throw it away.